# How can you create nested form groups dynamically in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am creating dynamic forms from using this example https://toddmotto.com/angular-dynamic-components-forms#dynamicfield

What I cant find is any reference to creating nested groups for such as a group for validating password/password confirm or grouping for address.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample application for comparing password. I have used RxwebValidator for  compare password. 
component code :

```js
 this.userFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
                password:['',], 
        confirmPassword:['', RxwebValidators.compare({fieldName:'password' })], 
                                });
```

That's it, write code on html as per angular practices. See the [compare password working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-form-validator-compare?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)